# installing @angular2-material using package.json and npm

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to build my css file from @angular2-material using a script in package.json.  However, I'm not able to get a working configuration.  Here is my build script:

```
"scripts":{
    "build:css": "node-sass --include-path node_modules --output client/styles client/styles/main.scss client/styles/bundle.css"
}
```

My main.scss looks like this:

```
@import "node_modules/@angular2-material/core/style/core.scss";
@import "node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox/checkbox.scss";
```

Does anyone have a working configuration?

Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240568/meteor-1-3-and-the-use-of-the-npm-module-angular2-material that was closed by moderators but which has now been viewed 86x.  I'd say there is a wish to know how to do this?  I'd be disappointed if this question gets closed!!  Might revert to raising on the project git if it is.

Answer (score 0):

in webpack 
simply do in app.module.ts

import {MaterialModule) from '@angular/material';

imports:[MaterialModule.forRoot()]

Thats it , now use material component anywhere